# flutter charts, making label a custom widget on donut chart

Tags: flutter, dart, charts

I'm using the flutter charts library and this example:

https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/pie_charts/auto_label

I want to use a material design icon instead of text.

Any hint? I went through old issues, API docs and examples but can't figure it out

Comment: After a quick look at that example and the library code, it appears to achieve this you would have to copy the library code locally, and modify the `Series` class to accept and display a `Widget`. Because as it is, it only gives you access to colors and Strings/nums. The `labelAccessorFn` attribute in the example is what is displaying the data.

Comment: Thanks Loren, I think that's the case too. Will just do a different design.